# App-to-app flow for flutter app with Truelayer

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, universal-link

I am trying to implement app-to-app flow from flutter mobile app to the UK bank's app. We are using [truelayer](https://truelayer.com/).  [Here](https://docs.truelayer.com/docs/initiating-payments-from-a-mobile-web-view) is the documentation from truelayer. This [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TrueLayer/mobile-webview-example) contains code from truelayer for sample iOS and Android apps configured for app-to-app redirects to work correctly.

For the flutter app, we are using [webview_flutter: ^3.0.4](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter).

It is not redirecting to the bank app, here is the code using webview_flutter package.

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewTruelayer extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewTruelayer({super.key});

  @override
  WebViewTruelayerState createState() => WebViewTruelayerState();
}

class WebViewTruelayerState extends State<WebViewTruelayer> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable virtual display.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Trulayer example'),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl:
            'https://truelayer-sandbox.com/test-redirect',
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Result:

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MicBU.gif)

[Expected result](https://i.imgur.com/ftW1dg4.gif) [Source code](https://github.com/TrueLayer/mobile-webview-example/tree/main/android)